# How to use graph.merge() py2neo v3 to replace graph.merge_one() in Nicole White's blog app

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I am trying to recreate Nicole White's [microblog application powered by Flask and Neo4j](https://nicolewhite.github.io/neo4j-flask/) tutorial but using py2neo v3 rather than v2. I'm a novice but keen to understand & learn by tinkering...

I know that graph.merge_one() has been replaced by graph.merge() in v3 but I cannot figure out how to get tags out of my database, or if they don't exist then create them in order to use them to create a relationship with a node.

Nicole does it like this using py2neo v2...

```
for tag in tags:
        t=graph.merge_one("Tag", "name", tag)
        rel=Relationship(t, "TAGGED", post)
        graph.create(rel)
```

How can I do it using graph.merge() from py2neo v3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to work but...

```
for tag in tags:
        t = Node("Tag", name=tag)
        graph.merge(t)
        rel=Relationship(t, "TAGGED", post)
        graph.create(rel)
```

I wish there was a tutorial to follow. The docs are so terse...

Comment: I really just wanted to upvote your comment about the poor documentation and wanting examples/tutorials to follow.  It's really hard to get anything done as it is.

Comment: I'll share info if I discover anything. @technige or anyone - how about it?